# Unable to push data to handlebars?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I used to use mustache.js for my templates on a quickbase app, but recently decided to switch over to trying handlebars so that I could use the if/then of it for a more appealing template.

However I can not seem to get them to work like mustache did, the Get for my module.js shows in the console, but after that the page doesn't load like it's supposed to (it usually loads the template.html)

module.js

```
var dbidApplication = "dbidHere";
var dbidTable = "dbidtHere";
var apptoken = "apptokenhere";
$.ajaxSetup({
    data: {
        apptoken: apptoken
    }
});
var promise1 = $.get(dbidApplication, {
    a: "dbpage",
    pagename: "template.html"
});
var promise2 = $.get(dbidTable, {
    act: "API_GenResultsTable",
    query: "{3.EX." + kRid + "}",
    jsa: 1,
    options: "num-1",
});
$.when(promise1, promise2).then(function(html, data) { 
    //do some stuff with all the data
    var template = Handlebars.compile(html[0]);
    console.log(html[0]);
    console.log(data[0]);
    console.log(qdb_data);
    $(template(qdb_data)).appendTo("#external");
```

});

My template has the source for handlebars and the div with id external

template.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.3/handlebars.runtime.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="external"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show us your html

Comment: Added the template.html page

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to set qdb_data:

```
$.when(promise1, promise2).then(function(html, data) { 
    //do some stuff with all the data
    var template = Handlebars.compile(html[0]);
    var qdb_data = data[0];
    console.log(html[0]);
    console.log(data[0]);
    console.log(qdb_data);
    $(template(qdb_data)).appendTo("#external");
});
```

Comment: Oh I meant to add that the qdb_data is what comes from the promise 2.     http://pastebin.com/ua56xwnx      I have tried qdb_data[0] also

Comment: Yes, the missing line you might have missed is to set it to qdb_data=data[0];

Comment: I'll give that a shot right quick, didn't think about that       EDIT: That didn't seem to work, nothing changed, still no logging in console on either chrome nor FF firebug